# How to stop my app pre populating div when search input is empty React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im building an app that users can search for certain pokemon cards by name but when running the app the div to show results is pre population random cards in the div when there is no user input in the search bar.

How can I stop data randomly populating until the user has input something into the search bar?

here is my code

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import CardOverview from "../components/CardOverview";
import styles from "./SearchCards.module.css";
import Select from "react-select";
import setOptions from "../data/sets";
import SpinnerOverride from "../utils/SpinnerOverride";
import SetOverview from "../components/SetOverview";

/**
 * The `SearchCards` component represents a page in my app
 * which allows the user to search for cards by their name
 * and filter them by their set.
 */

export default function Search() {
  // Track the `loading` state property of `SearchCards` page/component with the method `setLoading
  // this is true by default.
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  // Track the value of the `searchInput` state property with the method `setSearchInput` field
  // An empty string by default
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");

  // Track the value of the selected `set`state property of cards with method `setSet`
  // null by default
  const [set, setSet] = useState(null);

  // Track the `cards` state property that have been returned from the api with the `setCards` method
  // An empty array by default
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  const isMounted = useRef(true);

  // The base url for the api which will append extra info
  // to based on the users input/selections.
  const SEARCH_CARDS_BASE_URL = "https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards";

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchCards() {
      // update the `loading` state to `true`
      setLoading(true);

      // Transform the text in the search input field to lowercase
      // and remove any leading and trailing whitespace
      const cleanSearchInput = searchInput.toLowerCase().trim();

      // Format the fetch url based on whether the search input
      // and set filter values.
      let url = `${SEARCH_CARDS_BASE_URL}?`;
      if (set && set.value !== "all") {
        // if `set` is not null, and the value is not 'all', then
        // the user must have manually set the `set` using the set
        // filter, so append it to the url
        url += `q=set.id:${set.value}`;

        if (cleanSearchInput === "") {
          // If the user has not entered any input into the search
          // input, display the first 50 cards from the api
        } else {
          // If the user has entered something in the search input, then
          // search for all cards with that name
          url += ` name:${cleanSearchInput}`;
          isMounted.current = true;
        }
      } else {
        // Same ideas for both situations listed above, just with slightly
        // different string formatting due to the strange way the api wants
        // developers to format query params.
        if (cleanSearchInput === "") {
        } else {
          url += `q=name:${cleanSearchInput}`;
          isMounted.current = true;
        }
      }

      // Log out the final url which will be passed to the fetch
      // function -- for debugging purposes only.
      console.log(url);

      // Fetch the data from the API
      const resp = await fetch(url);

      // Parse the response into json
      const cards = await resp.json();

      // Update the `cards` state to be an array of card objects
      setCards(cards.data);

      // Wait 4 seconds before setting the `loading` state to false.
      // This gives react time to fully update the `cards` state.
      console.log("before set time out");
      setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(false);

        console.log("during set timeout");
      }, 3000);

      console.log("after set timeout");
    }

    // Call the `fetchCards` function
    fetchCards();

    // if either the `searchInput` or `set` values change
    // the `fetchCards` function will execute.
  }, [searchInput, set]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className={styles.header}>Search Pokemon</h1>

      <input
        className={styles.searchInput}
        type="text"
        value={searchInput}
        // When the text inside the search input field changes
        // update the value of the `searchInput` state
        onChange={(e) => setSearchInput(e.target.value)}
        placeholder={"e.g. Pikachu"}
      />

      <Select
        className={styles.setFilter}
        defaultValue={setOptions[0]}
        // When the filter option in the filter dropdown changes
        // update the the value of the `set` state
        onChange={(newSet) => setSet(newSet)}
        name="set"
        // `setOptions` is an array of objects, where each object
        // represents one set. See src/data/sets.js
        options={setOptions}
        classNamePrefix="select"
      />
      {loading ? (
        // If the `loading` state is true, display the loading spinner
        <SpinnerOverride />
      ) : !loading && cards.length === 0 ? (
        // If the `loading` state is false, and there are no cards
        // in the array, then tell the user that no cards have been
        // found

        <SetOverview />
      ) : (
        // If the app is not loading, and there are cards in the
        // `cards` array, then render them out on the screen for the
        // user to see.
        <div className={styles.flexboxContainer}>
          {cards.map((card, idx) => {
            // Pass the data for each card returned from the
            // api into the `CardOverview` component which will
            // render the data (image, name, set, etc) to the screen
            return (
              <div key={idx}>
                <CardOverview cardData={card} />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether the length of your search string is bigger than 0, if it is you render the cards div, otherwise, you don't.

Further Explanation as requested in comment:

```
        <div className={styles.flexboxContainer}>
          {searchInput.length > 0 ? cards.map((card, idx) => {
            return (
              <div key={idx}>
                <CardOverview cardData={card} />
              </div>
            );
          }) : null}
        </div>
```

Comment: I'm quite new to coding, how would I go about this ? thanks for your help

Comment: I added a code snippet at the bottom.

Comment: the outside return statement is wrong, just `cards.map`

Comment: niceman is correct, my mistake, I corrected it

Answer (score 0):

While @niklasbec's answer will work, I just wanted to add my cent.

you can inside `fetchCards` check for length of `searchInput` and return early if it's zero like this:

```
async function fetchCards(){
   if(searchInput.length === 0){
       return;
   }
   // rest of fetchCards
}
```

this way could make your JSX cleaner since you won't have nested ternary operators(`loading ? <SpinnerOverride /> : searchInput.length === 0 ? cards.map(// rest of expression`)

In the end, both ways achieve what you want, use the style you prefer.